# Combine Pipeline Resolver with Nested Resolvers - AppSync AWS

Tags: aws-appsync

I'm trying to combine pipeline resolvers with nested resolvers in order to centralize error handling in after mapping template.

My execution flow will be:

before template -> function 1 ( nested resolver template ) -> after template

The problem that I'm having is that in function 1, the child resolver are not trigger, only the parent resolver is trigger.

So my question is:

If I run pipeline resolver, can I have as a function a nested resolver?

Answer (score 0):

So what you can try to start off with is to create a central error handling function, which can be attached to the nested field in a pipeline resolver. Can you give us more detail about what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps some sample request / response?

Some details to keep in mind: The resolver on a parent field will get called before the resolver on a child (nested) field. You can use a central error handling function that is shared on both the parent. The result of the parent field will be exposed to the child (nested) field as $ctx.source.